# Property Sum translated to sql on IQueryable with linq to entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

Given two classes generated code first with EF, with a parent-child relation:

```
class Parent {
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children
}

class Child {
   //...
   public decimal Amount{ get; set; }
   public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create a property `Total` on Parent, something like

```
decimal Total => Children.Sum(child => child.UnitPrice * child.Amount)
```

But if I do this like that, and then do

```
var list = ctx.Parents
                  .Where(p => p.Total > 1000)
                  .Select(p => new {
                       p.Id, 
                       p.Total,
                       Count = p.Children.Count });
foreach(var item in list){
      Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.} ...");
}
```

I got an error that says

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: The specified type member 'Total' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

While, at my opinion, it should not be that hard for EF to generate an query using `SUM(UnitPrice * Amount) as Total` I can't get it working.

I have already tried it with a static expression like

```
  public static Expression<Func<Parent, decimal>> GetTotal()
  {
      return p=> p.Children.Sum(line => line.ItemQty * line.UnitPrice);
  }
```

While it should be acceptable to do this calculation just in code. I want to use this example to learn more about how to use IQueryable.

**A Little Succes**

Given the following static property on Parent

```
  public static Expression<Func<Parent, decimal?>> Total =>
        p=> (from c in p.Childeren
             select c.UnitPrice * c.ItemQty).Sum();
```

And then doing

```
var list = ctx.Parents.Select(Parent.Total);
```

I got a list containing all the totals, and I see that EF generated the following query

> ```
> SELECT
>     (SELECT
>         SUM([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1]
>         FROM ( SELECT
>             [Extent2].[UnitPrice] *  CAST( [Extent2].[Amount] AS decimal(19,0)) AS [A1]
>             FROM [dbo].[Child] AS [Extent2]
>             WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ParentId]
>         )  AS [Filter1]) AS [C1]
>     FROM [dbo].[Parent] AS [Extent1]
> ```

So, it EF is indeed capable of translating the Sum() method to SQL. now I only need to use it in the Where().

Answer (score 1):

Calculated properties are only known in the class, not in the database. You'll need to instantiate your objects (into classes) before you can access these calculated properties.

It's not that hard to get this to work:

```
var list = ctx.Parents
              .Where(p => p.Total > 1000)
              .ToList() //This instantiates your data into objects
              .Select(p => new {
                   p.Id, 
                   p.Total,
                   Count = p.Children.Count });
```

This may require an include statement, depending on whether you've got lazy loading or not:

```
var list = ctx.Parents
              .Include(p => p.Children) //Children will be populated upon instantiation
              .Where(p => p.Total > 1000)
              .ToList() //This instantiates your data into objects
              .Select(p => new {
                   p.Id, 
                   p.Total,
                   Count = p.Children.Count });
```

---

> While, at my opinion, it should not be that hard for EF to generate an query using `SUM(UnitPrice * Amount) as Total` I can't get it working.

There's more to it than you're mentioning.

The `SUM` of what? Not of the **current** result (which is the `Parents` table), you want a sum of a calculation done on the `Children` table (grouped by `ParentId`), which is a completely different dataset than the one you've been working with so far.

This is why EF won't do what you want it to do. It's trying to decide on the `SELECT` part of the query, but your expectation requires a much more complex query body; one which joins children and parents together in order to perform a calculation on the children and then sum those outcomes into a single value.

If you try writing the SQL query yourself, you'll see that it's **much** more complicated than just doing `SUM(UnitPrice * Amount) as Total`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. We are indeed solving performance issues (more complex scenarios than this) where EF requires up to 9 seconds while a query by hand does it in less than 300ms. I am investigate the capabilities of EF because I don't want go back to writing sql queries by hand and duplication of Business Logic in the DB.

Comment: @StijnVanAntwerpen EF is an additional layer. At best, you're going to get equivalent performance (or negligibly different performance) compared to handcrafting an SQL query. EF is limited by what it can implicitly convert from C# to SQL.

Comment: Well, I know EF has it limits to translate c# to sql (of course, it still doesn't use magic). I was hoping stuff like Sum() was supported... If I indeed define a view in the DB (VW_ParentWithTotal) an let EF generate the model from that, the overhead is neglectable. But  I am trying to eliminate that step. (since VW_ParentWithTotal has BL in it that is already present in c#)